# Deploy Angular App w/ Proxy for One Route

Tags: node.js, angular, http, deployment, proxy

I have an Angular app w/ a proxy that's working well in local. There's one route that utilizes it with a Node API call.

Node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const api_service = require('./apiService');
const app = express();

app.get('/getData/:date', (req, res) => {
  const date = req.params.date;
  api_service.fetchData(...)
    .then(response => {
      res.json(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.send(error)
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started in port 3000!");
});
```

Function in my Angular Service:

```
  fetchData(date: string) {
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      responseType: 'text',
    };
    this._http
      .get<string>('/api/getData/' + date)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          this.result = data;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.mediaSource.next(this.result);
        if (Object.keys(this.result).length != 0) {
          this.history.push(this.result);
        }
      });
  }
```

proxy-prod.config.json

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "https://example.com",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }
    }
}
```

proxy-local.conf.json

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

angular.json

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui-dev:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy-local.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ui-dev:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy-prod.config.json"
            }
          }
        },
```

ng serve works perfectly.
ng serve --prod and ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none do not.

The error I'm getting is:

```
headers: d, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'myexample.com', ok: false
```

I've tried this in my request but they cause errors too:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
{ headers, responseType: 'text'}
```

Been searching, testing, and dissecting code for many hours and not sure how to proceed. Can you anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: I think the angular proxy only works in serve as that is using the webpack server. Prod mode uses a different server.

Comment: The dev proxy is intended to locally simulate your actual production environment. Neither it nor the rest of the dev server are intended to be used in prod. If you actually need a proxy in the real environment, you'll have to deploy one.

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne. That's what I've read. Do you know how to configure that? I mean, where is this done? Is there something I need to do in my hosting setup or via Angular? I haven't been able to find a clear and current way to accomplish this.

Comment: Makes sense @jonrsharpe. Is this done via Angular's environments directory?

Comment: No, that would be entirely separate to Angular.

Comment: For the live (production) nodejs server, you probably just want to implement the proper cors headers so you don’t need a proxy.

Comment: Do you mean like this:
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://example.com/route'
}));

Comment: Added this node with no avail:
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
})

Comment: Adding cors headers to node did fix the Angular prod error, but still persists in ng build.